# ssh session not closing in bash script

Tags: bash, ssh

I am sshing to a system and rebooting it in a while loop, however the ssh session does not close so the the script is just hanging after the first reboot. I have tried various ways to close it, any idea? I never get to the echo "test".

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
echo "Executing SSH session to 192.168.1.1..."
sshpass -p "pass" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@192.168.1.1 << ! 
./reset.sh 
! 
echo "test"
sleep 20
done
```

reset.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
if [  -e /dev/ttyUSB2 ]  && [  -e /dev/ttyUSB5 ]; then {
reboot -f
}
fi
```

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro added reset.sh basically just reboots the system (the usb's are always there), I'll try replacing !

Comment: What happens if you just login manually on the command line and say `reboot -f`? Does the SSH session close nicely or is it left hanging? If the ssh client doesn't get any indication of the session closing when the server shuts down, it waits a potentially long time before noticing the connection is dead.

Comment: @ilkkachu It's left hanging, I guess it is just waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What can be happing is the remote session being lost as you are asking for a reboot, and so the system will hang some time waiting for the remote system to answer.

I would introduce before that `sshpass` a timeout command, like `timeout` or `timelimit` as in:

```
timeout 10s sshpass ...
```

As for `ssh` services, try to avoid using passwords, and instead use RSA certificate authentication. Not sure about that particular sshpass command, but often, if the binary being called does not takes precautions, the password can be seen with `ps` when used in the command line.

Comment: I will try this now, however if the ssh is not successful then the echo will be printed and the loop will work, so it is probably not the problem. Will let you know, thanks.

Comment: The word used in a here-document may be `!`, that's not a problem (other than being an odd choice of delimiter).

Comment: @Kusalananda Hmmm interesting. If it has that, than  it is a matter of following the `timelimit/timeout` recommendation.

Comment: I think `!` is only special with history expansion, and that shouldn't be on by default in a noninteractive shell

Comment: @Kusalananda you are right, changed the answer for what was the spirit of the last recommendation already there.

Comment: Thanks, timeout will do as ssh is just not getting a message to close.

Comment: Another option would be to use `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` on the SSH client to ask it to check that the server stays responsive. `ssh -oServerAliveInterval=1 ...` would cut the connection after about 3 seconds of the server going silent, since the max count is 3 by default.

Comment: `sshpass`'s man page explicitly warns against using `-p`: _"Sshpass makes a minimal  attempt  to  hide the password, but such attempts are doomed to create race conditions without actually solving the problem."_. Luckily, it also supports passing the password through the environment, or a file.